# Does a user process have any control over paging?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

A program might have some data that, when needed, it wants to access very fast. Let's call this VIP data. It would like to reduce the likelihood that page in memory that the VIP data resides on gets swapped to disk when memory utilization is high on the system. What types of control/influence does it have over this?

For example, I think it can consider the page replacement policy and try to influence the OS to not swap this VIP data to disk. If the policy is LRU, the program can periodically read the VIP data to ensure that the page has always been accessed fairly recently. A program can also use a very small amount of memory in total, making it likely that all its pages are recently accessed when it runs and therefore the VIP data is not likely swapped to disk.

Can it exert any more explicit control over paging?

Comment: What are you asking about? If you want forbid swapping you may just mark appropriate region of memory as not swappable. As real implication you can consider mlock.

Comment: Exactly what I was asking about - I didn't know about mlock, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you might consider

- Prioritising the process using [renice](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/renice.1.html) command or
- Lock the processes in the main memory using [MLOCK(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely operating system dependent. On some systems, if you have appropriate privileges you can lock pages in physical memory.